# .NET property generating “must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern”

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I have checked the similar questions that the "questions with similar titles" result but they were all targeting .net 3.5 I am targeting 4.0 and **I am getting must declare a body because it is not marked abstract,extern,or partial**

**Why am I getting this error and how can i prevent it without making my prope abstract,extern or partial? thank you very much**

```
      public static SRDataContext DC
    {
        get
        {
            if (DC == null)
            {
                DC = new SRDataContext();
            }
            return DC;
        }
        private set
        {
            DC = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am thinking you need a backing static field for this to work. Looks like your using property recursively in your getters and setters.

Comment: that is the line the error list is giving me, and intellisense is highlighting the set keyword

Comment: The code you are giving should compile. Although it won't work, you need to have a backing field to do this.

Comment: An error like the one you mention, can also be caused by an earlier part of the code that wasn't properly closed with curly brackets. The code you show will compile and is not the (real) cause of the error. (note: I hope this is not your real code, as you cause eternal recursion with getting the property itself inside the gettor)

Comment: Just a note: most things that are true about .NET 3.5 are also true about .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static SRDataContext dc;

public static SRDataContext DC
{
    get
    {
        if (dc == null)
        {
            dc = new SRDataContext();
        }
        return dc;
    }
    private set
    {
        dc = value;
    }
}
```

You need a backing field for the property (a field where the data can be saved). In C# there are the auto properties, but they can't have a body. Their backing field is created "behind your back" by the C# compiler. So for example:

```
public static SRDataContext DC { get; private set; }
```

But it would be different from what you are trying to do.

Comment: While this is an error in the code, I think shouldn't cause any compile-time errors.

Comment: @svick You are right. It compiles perfectly :-) (but better not to run it)... If he has other problems he will ask again for help :-)

Comment: You'd better make that backing field private.